# Book where alien monkeys cause stars to twinkle

Tags: story-identification

My wife read a book several years ago, but lost it. A boy and a girl (teenagers) travel into space and discover that alien monkeys are what cause the stars to twinkle.
At one point they are climbing up some tall thing, and might have to fight off some of the aliens.
She read this about 12-15 years ago, and is either a teen novel or a young adult novel. 
Not much to go off, but any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: This may be the champion "whaaaaat?" story ID question.

Comment: I wish she could remember more, she lent the book to her dad who has a strange philosophy of throwing away books when he finishes reading them... I will go through the checklist and see if it jogs any more details from her memory